# Artifacts when using boolean modifier (difference) on simple mesh

Tags: modifiers, artifacts, boolean-modifier

I am rather new to Blender so most likely my problem has a simple solution but despite by online search I could not find any similar example.

I have quite a simple mesh and I am trying to cut some holes from that mesh. I want to use modifiers as they simplify changes that I might have to make regarding cuts.

[image]

So the first boolean is similar to making the inset and removing it. At that stage everything looks pretty OK.

[image]

The object that is used for boolean operation looks very similar to first one.

[image]

Real problems starts when I want to add second ad third cut. In both cases (second and third cut) the object used for boolean operation are identical - a simple cubes.

[image]

The final result depends on the positioning of those two cubes. In some cases there are no artifacts in some cases they are pretty visible.

[image]
[image]
[image]

All object has Shade Flat and all objects has Normals outwards.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to have a look at your .blend file, but I would recommend adding the three objects you are using as boolean objects into a single mesh:

- In object mode, select all 3 boolean objects using Shift+Left-click
- Use CTRL+J to join the meshes into a single object.

You should then be able to use this single object and a single boolean modifier to make your cuts. This may help to resolve your issue, thought it's difficult to say for certain without taking a look at the file.

Also, Blender sometimes struggles to handle overlapping normals, and it looks like the normals of some of your boolean objects are overlapping.

You could maybe try moving the the faces on your two cube-shaped boolean objects so they do not overlap with the centre boolean object.